# Gurobi Error Divisor must be a constant when making a more complex objective function

Tags: python, gurobi

When I use a fairly straight forward cost function for my optimization objective function, gurobi gives back an answer but when I complicate things with `math.log()` functions or even with `i**2` instead of `i*i` it produces an error similar to one of the following:

`GurobiError: Divisor must be a constant`

`TypeError: a float is required`

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'Var' and 'int'`

I tried to reformulate `math.log((m-i)/i)` to `math.log(m-i)- math.log(i)` this produces the float is required error. changing `i*i` to `i**2` produces unsupported error.

Now my question is: is it just impossible to make a more complex function within Gurobi? or am I making an mistake elsewhere.

Here is a snippit of my model

```
from gurobipy import *
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import math

start_time = time.time()


# example NL (i, 20, 0.08, -6.7, 301)
def cost(i, j, k, l, m):
    cost = (j - l)*i + k*i*i - l*(m - i) * (math.log((m - i) / i ))
    return cost


def utility(i, j, k, l):
    utility = j + k*i + l*i*i
    return utility

"""
def cost(i, j, k, l):
    cost = j + k*i + .5*l*i*i
    return cost
"""

# assign files to use as input and as output
outputfile = 'model1nodeoutput.csv'
inputfile = 'marketclearinginput.xlsx'

# define dataframes
dfdemand = pd.read_excel(inputfile, sheetname="demand", encoding='utf8')
dfproducer = pd.read_excel(inputfile, sheetname="producer", encoding='utf8')

m = Model("1NodeMultiPeriod")

dofprod = [m.addVar(lb=3.0, ub=300, name=h) for h in dfproducer['name']]
dofdem = [m.addVar(lb=3.0, ub=300, name=h) for h in dfdemand['name']]

# Integrate new variables
m.update()

# Set objective
m.setObjective(quicksum([utility(i, j, k, l) for i, j, k, l
                        in zip(dofdem, dfdemand['c'], dfdemand['a'], dfdemand['b'])]) -
               quicksum([cost(i, j, k, l, m) for i, j, k, l, m
                        in zip(dofprod, dfproducer['c'], dfproducer['a'], dfproducer['b'], dfproducer['Pmax'])]),
               GRB.MAXIMIZE)

# Set constraints
# Set constraints for producers
for i, j, k in zip(dofprod, dfproducer['Pmin'], dfproducer['Pmax']):
    m.addConstr(i >= j)
    m.addConstr(i <= k)
# Set constraints for demand
for i, j, k in zip(dofdem, dfdemand['Pmin'], dfdemand['Pmax']):
    m.addConstr(i >= j)
    m.addConstr(i <= k)
# Build the timestamp list, pd or np unique both possible, pd faster and preserves order
# Timestamps skips the first 3 symbols (example L1T2034 becomes 2034)
timestamps = pd.unique([i.varName[3:] for i in dofprod])
# Set constraint produced >= demanded (this should be te last constraint added for shadow variables)
for h in timestamps:
    m.addConstr(quicksum([i for i in dofprod if i.varName.endswith(h)]) >=
                quicksum([i for i in dofdem if i.varName.endswith(h)]))


m.optimize()
```

Comment: Could you find the solution for the divisor must be constant? I have the same problem!

Answer (score -1):

Your problem might have to do with the Gurobi quicksum() function. Perhaps try sum().

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Using sum instead of quicksum does not change anything!